# How can I order React components on a page so that they appear in a column

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to have my React components that are created based on user input stacked like this:

```
            |Component|
            |Component|
            |Component|
            |Component|
            |Component|
```

I want them to to be in the middle of the page, and stacked on on top of the other. However, they are currently ending up on the left side stacked like that.

This is my CSS code:

```
.ingredients-input-bar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(71, 79, 105);
    justify-content: center;
    width: 400px;
}
```

This is the code for the input bar:

```
    return (
        <div className='ingredients-input-bar'>
            <form>
                <input
                    type='number'
                    id='quantity'
                    value={quantity}
                    onChange={getVariables}
                />
            </form>
            <h3>New Quantity: {fractionalize( ( (props.newServings / props.originalServings) * quantity) )}</h3>

        </div>
```

And this code builds all of the input bars:

```
export const IngredientsInput = (props) => {
    let inputBars = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < props.numIngredients; i++) {
        inputBars.push(
                            <IngredientsInputBar
                            newServings={props.newServings}
                            originalServings={props.originalServings} />);
    }
    return inputBars;
```

Comment: Couple of questions. 1. How do they appear right now. Can you post a screenshot? 2. Whats the html/css of the component that holds your list?

Comment: This link might help you
http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't render elements like that. You should use `.map` function in react. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) you can read more about it.

This should work.

```
const numIngredients = new Array(5).fill("");
```

This line just creates and array of empty strings depending on a number. In your code it will be `props.numIngredients`

```
 const numIngredients = new Array(5).fill("");
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        margin: "auto",
        flexDirection: "column",
        width: "400px"
      }}
    >
      {numIngredients.map(() => (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>One div</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

I created working example for you with flex - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-k1owj?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I think this should be a comment as it does not attempt to solve the problem

Comment: @litelite did you even check it? I created working example

Comment: Then you should post the code in the answer. Because link only answer are bad as they can rot

Comment: Also, the elements are still aligned on the left. Not centered as mentioned in the question

Comment: No, they are not, check it again. Text is aligned to the left, not elements

Comment: Right. Forgot to check that. But still, you should post the code as text in the answer and explain how it solves the problem